# identity seed lost efter publishing new table in merge replication

Tags: sql-server, identity, merge-replication

I have a merge replication in MSSQL 2008 and a little over 200 windows mobile 6 clients that subscribes to this replication.

When I publish a new table in the replication, for some reason, every subscriber loses identity seed after they make a sync. They all start their identities on 1 after this.

If they drop the database and download a new one the identity seed "works" again. Does anyone know why this is happening or what i could do to not get this behaviour?

Comment: Maybe these two articles helps you: [Replicate Identity Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152543.aspx) and [How to: Manage Identity Columns (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146907(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have read those articles and unfortunately they did not help. the identity seed does work most of the time and is set up correctly from what i can read on the internet. but once in a while some new functionality needs another table and that is when the problem occurs.